# Oracle SQL - Dates from/to from a table with dates

Tags: oracle, pattern-matching, gaps-and-islands

I have a problem that I do not know how is the best way to solve it:

I have the following information:

| PRODUCT | IS_BUY | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 01/01/2021 |
| A | 1 | 02/01/2021 |
| A | 1 | 03/01/2021 |
| A | 0 | 04/01/2021 |
| A | 1 | 05/01/2021 |
| A | 1 | 06/01/2021 |
| B | 1 | 01/01/2021 |
| C | 1 | 01/01/2021 |
| C | 0 | 02/01/2021 |
| C | 0 | 03/01/2021 |
| C | 1 | 04/01/2021 |

I need the following result to be left where for each product the date between where it exists or does not buy:

| PRODUCT | IS_BUY | FROM_DATE | TO_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 01/01/2021 | 04/01/2021 |
| A | 0 | 04/01/2021 | 05/01/2021 |
| A | 1 | 05/01/2021 | null |
| B | 1 | 01/01/2021 | null |
| C | 1 | 01/01/2021 | 02/01/2021 |
| C | 0 | 02/01/2021 | 04/01/2021 |
| C | 1 | 04/01/2021 | null |

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please note: Oracle SQL is not called "PL/SQL". PL/SQL is something entirely different. I won't tell you what it is - I am sure you can use Google search to find out. I changed your tags accordingly (and the title of your question).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell us your Oracle version. Below I will show two solutions: first the more advanced one, using the `match_recognize` clause, added in Oracle 12.1, and then the older approach, using the Tabibitosan method for solving gaps-and-islands problems (the class that your problem belongs to).

Data setup:

```
create table my_data (product, is_buy, eff_date) as
  select 'A', 1, to_date('01/01/2021', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
  select 'A', 1, to_date('02/01/2021', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
  select 'A', 1, to_date('03/01/2021', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
  select 'A', 0, to_date('04/01/2021', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
  select 'A', 1, to_date('05/01/2021', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
  select 'A', 1, to_date('06/01/2021', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
  select 'B', 1, to_date('01/01/2021', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
  select 'C', 1, to_date('01/01/2021', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
  select 'C', 0, to_date('02/01/2021', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
  select 'C', 0, to_date('03/01/2021', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
  select 'C', 1, to_date('04/01/2021', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
;
```

**(By the way, this is the preferred way to include sample data in your posts!)**

Note that `date` is a reserved keyword; I changed the column name to `eff_date`.

First solution, using `match_recognize` to match patterns in the data:

```
select product, is_buy, eff_date, end_date
from   my_data
match_recognize(
  partition by product
  order     by eff_date
  measures  a.is_buy       as is_buy, 
            a.eff_date     as eff_date,
            next(eff_date) as end_date
  pattern   ( a b* )
  define    b as is_buy = a.is_buy
);

PRODUCT IS_BUY EFF_DATE   END_DATE  
------- ------ ---------- ----------
A            1 01/01/2021 04/01/2021
A            0 04/01/2021 05/01/2021
A            1 05/01/2021           
B            1 01/01/2021           
C            1 01/01/2021 02/01/2021
C            0 02/01/2021 04/01/2021
C            1 04/01/2021
```

Second solution, using only analytic functions and aggregation (Tabibitosan method):

```
with prep as (
  select product, is_buy, eff_date,
         lead(eff_date) over (partition by product 
                              order by eff_date) as next_date,
         row_number() over (partition by product         order by eff_date) -
         row_number() over (partition by product, is_buy order by eff_date)
                 as grp
  from   my_data
)
select product, is_buy, min(eff_date) as eff_date,
       max(next_date) keep (dense_rank last order by eff_date) as end_date
from   prep
group  by product, is_buy, grp
order  by product, eff_date
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select
Product,
Is_Buy,
(select  min(x.DATE) from products x where x.product=a.product and x.is_buy=a.is_buy) from_date,
(select  max(x.DATE) from products x where x.product=a.product and x.is_buy=a.is_buy) to_date,
from products a
group by a.Product, a.Is_Buy
```